# How to sort data from a Json by distance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sorting

I want to sort the items by the one closest to the user, currently showing them but sorted by id (default). I have managed to sort them through sort but it does not seem to work.

My code JS:

```
$(function() {
     $.getJSON('clients?transform=1', function(data) {
         $.each(data.clients, function(i, f) {
          var distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(position.latitude,position.longitude,f.Latitude,f.Longitude).toFixed(1);
              var tblRow = "<li>" + "<div class='distance'>" + distance + "</div>" + "<span>" + f.nombre + "</span>" + "</li>";

            $(tblRow).sort(function(a, b){return a-b;}).appendTo("#cercademi");
       });
     });
  });
```

In my html, no order by distance. Im tried in several ways. 
Note: this project actually works in angularjs 1.5.8 and js.

Comment: can you provide example input and output that you want to use? also why are you using jquery and angularjs together?

Comment: What is `data.clients`? It could be an array, but JSON is commonly an object. Your current `.sort` is being used on each table row jquery object, that will not sort the whole table.

Comment: My json url is: [link](https://viveenunclick.com/api.php/clientes?transform=1)[/link]

Comment: My json url is: [link](https://viveenunclick.com/api.php/clientes?transform=1)[/link] and my html is:  

    <ul id="cercademi"></ul>

And output on load html (850 records from api): 

    <ul id="cercademi">
                  <li><div class="distance">6.1</div>
                  <span>A21</span></li>
                  <li><div class="distance">1.1</div>
                  <span>ADN sport</span></li>
    </ul>

No order the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first calculate all distances and only then perform the sort (and only once). I would in fact extend the `f` object with a distance property, and then chain the sort to the list of such mutated objects.

Some other remarks:

- the `$.map` callback will get the array value as first argument, not as second.
- the JSON you receive has a `clientes` property, not `clients`

Working snippet (with dummy getDistanceFromLatLonInKm function and position):

```js
$(function() {
    var position = {}; // actual position is not important for this demo
    $.getJSON("https://viveenunclick.com/api.php/clientes?transform=1", function (data) {
        $("#cercademi").append(
            $.map(data.clientes, function(f) {
                f.distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(position.latitude,
                                position.longitude,f.Latitude,f.Longitude);
                return f;
            }).sort(function(f1, f2) {
                return f1.distance - f2.distance;
            }).map(function (f) {
                return "<li><div class='distance'>" + f.distance.toFixed(1) + "</div>" + 
                                    "<span>" + f.nombre + "</span></li>";
            })
        );
    });
});

// Dummy implementation, just to make it work
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm() {
    return Math.random() * 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="cercademi"></ul>
```

Comment: I already try this, but it does not show me anything, console comes out: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

I have jquery 1.10.2 Will this be?

Comment: No, that jQuery version can deal with this code. It means your data is different than expected. Can you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));` and make sure the root object has property `clients`, and that `clients` is an array? It would of course be better if you would provide sample data in your question.

Comment: Oh wait, I see in comments you provided a link: well it is clear your data does not have a `clients` property, but `clientes`.